# Differential of $ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\int_{s}^{t} \sigma(\tau)dW(\tau)+(r(\tau)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(\tau)^{2})d\tau} c(s)ds $

Tags: calculus, stochastic-integrals

I think -- using the chain rule -- it's

$$ e^{\int_{t}^{t}\cdots d\tau} c(t)dt \cdot e^{\int_{s}^{t} \sigma(\tau)dW(\tau)+(r(\tau)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(\tau)^{2})d\tau}\cdot \left(\sigma(t)dW(t)+(r(t)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(t)^{2})dt\right) \\
 =c(t)dt \cdot e^{\int_{s}^{t} \sigma(\tau)dW(\tau)+(r(\tau)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(\tau)^{2})d\tau}\cdot \left(\sigma(t)dW(t)+(r(t)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(t)^{2})dt\right) $$

Is this right?

Comment: The differential of $e^{\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(\tau)dW(\tau)+(r(\tau)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(\tau)^{2})d\tau}$ is not $e^{\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(\tau)dW(\tau)+(r(\tau)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(\tau)^{2})d\tau}\left(\sigma(t) \,\mathrm{d}W_t+(r(t)-1/2\sigma^2(t))\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$ - use Itô's formula.

Comment: Okay, so call $ X(t)=\sigma(t)dW(t)+(r(t)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(t)^{2})dt $, and $ Y(t)=u(X(t),t)=e^{\int_{s}^{t}X(\tau)d\tau} $

Comment: What is the differential of $e^{X(t)}$ (by Itô's formula)?